# Installing packages in virtual environment using anaconda for different projects

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

Do we need to install same conda packages repeatedly for different virtual environments? Is there a way to reuse python packages from one virtualenv to other? Is there a way to use global conda packages within a virtual environment?

Comment: A `conda` virtual environment? Like `conda activate <virenv name>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the packages in one environment to other using the following command..

**conda create -n  --clone**

For example , default environment is "base" and i want to copy it to a new env "new" , then...

```
conda create -n new --clone base
```

For more options , type ...

```
conda create -h
```

Comment: Thanks !! This is exactly I was looking for